# diseñar pagina html que esta dentro de un php

Tags: php, html, diseño

Buen dia,

Tengo una pagina en html que esta en un archivo .php que muestra ciertas cosas despues de que se inicia sesion, es decir al principio del archivo index.php tengo

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $now = time();

    if($now > $_SESSION['expire']) 
    {
        session_destroy();
        echo "Su sesion a terminado,
        <a href='login.html'>Necesita Hacer Login para ver el contenido</a>";
        exit;
    }
    ?>

<html>
    Aqui la pagina donde si todo esta bien arriba, se mostrará
</html>
```

---

la cuestion es que al abrir este archivo en dreamweaver el lo detecta obviamente como archivo php y no puedo mover divs, organizar, dar tamaños etc... debo hacerlo con codigo como tal...

hay algun software que me ayude con esto? si pudiera lo haria en un .html pero como debe ir despues del inicio de sesion pues no puedo

gracias!

Comment: Developer Tools...

Comment: Dreamweaver nos es una herramienta adecuada para diseño ni programación, suele ocasionar problemas duplicando código php (como definir funciones y validaciones) y con html cuando usas posicionamiento absoluto, de hecho, en ocasiones ni cuenta te das. Pero bueno, la solución es relativamente sencilla: Crea un archivo HTML, haz el diseño como prefieras y luego copia todo el código a tu script PHP.

Answer (score 0):

El archivo .php es sólo para validar la sesión, en caso que este perdida la sesión te muestra en html

"Necesita Hacer Login para ver el contenido"

y al dar clic te manda al archivo de login.html que supongo es el que quieres editar.

busca el archivo login.html y ábrelo en el dreamweaver.

por que en si ese archivo php trae ambas cosas codigo php y html 
aunque te faltan etiquetas como

Aqui la pagina donde si todo esta bien arriba, se mostrará

Comment: no es el login.html lo que quiero editar, en caso de que la sesion termine irá alla... lo que quiero editar es lo que esta entre las etiquetas html que esta en el mismo archivo donde se valida la sesion, es decir, en caso de que la sesion este OK, muestre la pagina, esa es a la que me refiero que esta en el codigo php y no puedo editar facilmente

Comment: Pues usa el Dreamweaver ponla en viista de diseño para que veas el puro HTML y ahi agregas las etiquetas que desees pero complementa tu código html de esta manera